# Complexity analysis of SelectionSort

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Here's a SelectionSort routine I wrote. Is my complexity analysis that follows correct?

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] numbers) {

    // Iterate over each cell starting from the last one and working backwards
    for (int i = numbers.length - 1; i >=1; i--)
    {
        // Always set the max pos to 0 at the start of each iteration
        int maxPos = 0;

        // Start at cell 1 and iterate up to the second last cell
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
        {
            // If the number in the current cell is larger than the one in maxPos,
            // set a new maxPos
            if (numbers[j] > numbers[maxPos])
            {
                maxPos = j;
            }
        }

        // We now have the position of the maximum number. If the maximum number is greater
        // than the number in the current cell swap them
        if (numbers[maxPos] > numbers[i])
        {
            int temp = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = numbers[maxPos];
            numbers[maxPos] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

**Complexity Analysis**

Outter Loop (comparison & assignment): 2 ops performed n times = 2n ops

Assigning maxPos: n ops

Inner Loop (comparison & assignment): 2 ops performed 2n^2 times = 2n² ops

Comparison of array elements (2 array references & a comparison): 3n² ops

Assigning new maxPos: n² ops

Comparison of array elements (2 array references & a comparison): 3n² ops

Assignment & array reference: 2n² ops

Assignment & 2 array references: 3n² ops

Assignment & array reference: 2n² ops

**Total number of primitive operations**

2n + n + 2n² + 3n² + n^2 + 3n² + 2n² + 3n² + 2n² = 16n² + 3n

Leading to Big Oh(n²)

Does that look correct? Particularly when it comes to the inner loop and the stuff inside it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, O(N<sup>2</sup>) is correct.

Edit: It's a *little* hard to guess at exactly what they may want as far as "from first principles" goes, but I would guess that they're looking for (in essence) something on the order of a proof (or at least indication) that the basic definition of big-O is met:

> there exist positive constants **c** and **n<sub>0</sub>** such that:
>
> 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>.

So, the next step after finding 16N<sup>2</sup>+3N would be to find the correct values for n<sub>0</sub> and c. At least at first glance, c appears to be 16, and n<sub>0</sub>, -3, (which is probably treated as 0, negative numbers of elements having no real meaning).

Comment: But I am wondering if my derivation is correct? Is this the correct way of performing complexity analysis from first principles?

Comment: @Jim_CS: Open to question. Most people *typically* start by basically eliminating the constant-complexity operations, so they never really look at the exact number of assignments, comparisons, etc., and in essence say: "f(N) constant complexity operations, therefore O(f(N))".

Comment: I have exam coming up and in the past exam papers sometimes its asks us to just derive an O-notation complexity function algorithms and sometimes it asks specifically to derive from 'first principles' the complexity of various sorting algorithms. So I presume 'first principles' here means primitive operations?

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is pointless (and incorrect) to add up actual operations, because operations take various numbers of processor cycles, some of them dereference values from memory which takes a lot more time, then it gets even more complex because compilers optimize code, then you have stuff like cache locality, etc, so unless you know **really, really well** how everything works underneath, you are adding up apples and oranges. You can't just add up "j < i", "j++", and "numbers[i] = numbers[maxPos]" as if they were equal, and you don't need to do so - for the purpose of complexity analysis, a constant time block is a constant time block. You are not doing low level code optimization.

The complexity is indeed N^2, but your coefficients are meaningless.

Comment: I understand that, I am talking about a 'simple perfect world' scenario, where all primitive operations are equal and it is as straightforward as adding them up. In that case I think the co-efficients have meaning. I know it's not that simple in practise but this has to be done for the exam.

Answer (score 0):

When you're swapping the array element at maxPos with the last element of the unsorted array, you're complexity analysis is wrong as these statements are in the outer loop.

Comparison of array elements (2 array references & a comparison): 3(n-1) ops

Assignment & array reference: 2(n-1) ops

Assignment & 2 array references: 3(n-1) ops

Assignment & array reference: 2(n-1) ops